# Change query parameter using .htaccess & redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm not good at .htaccess & I want to change query parameter of url & redirect to other URL

Here is my condition:

-If URL has parameter called share_id=xxx than it changes to other paremeter & redirect

Ex:

My current url: http://www.wpstructure.com/870/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/?share_id=883

& I want to redirect to: http://www.wpstructure.com/870/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/#share_id-883

Replace **?** with **#** and **=** with **-** only if URL has query paremeter **share_id**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^share_id=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /870/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/#share_id-%1? [NC,R,L]
```

Or try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/\?share_id=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1/#share_id-%2? [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: URL **http://www.wpstructure.com/870/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/?share_id=883**  is dynamic so how can i get **/870/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/**

Comment: Not working..it redirect to **http://www.wpstructure.com/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/%23share_id-top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch** and **#** is not coming in url i thinks it's encoded

Comment: ok..just tell me how can i get **/870/top-10-best-movies-a-must-watch/** this part from url

Comment: You can use the second solution I provided, it captures dynmic url paths and then uses it as %1.

Comment: Ok.......Thanks it's working fine...just need to change condition parameter **NC** to **NE** then it's not encoding **#**